# How to preselect a paper-item in a paper-dropdown-menu from model data?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I have an `iron-form` to do `CRUD` in my project. This works well, apart of one problem.

How can I get the `paper-dropdown-menu` to show the value from the model data ? (That is: preselect `paper-item` corresponding to the [[o.id]] value from my model data)

The `selected` attribute of `paper-menu` does not help because it's index-based and not based on the value of a `paper-item`.

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="itemForm" method="post" action="/api/item/edit">

    <input is="iron-input" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{item.id}}">

    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Title" selected-item="{{selectedTitle}}">
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}" as="o">
                <paper-item value="[[o.id]]">[[o.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <input is="iron-input" name="title" type="hidden" value$="[[selectedTitle.value]]">

    <paper-input name="firstName" label="First name" value="{{item.firstName}}"></paper-input>

    <paper-button raised onclick="document.getElementById('itemForm').submit()">Save</paper-button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

First, you cannot use `selected-item` for two-way data binding 'cause it's *read-only*.

Instead, you should be using `selected` on the `paper-menu` like this -

```
<paper-menu id="menu" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedValue}}" attr-for-selected="value">
```

Note that you need to specify the `attr-for-selected` to tell the `selected` property which attribute to use for selection. You also need to create a `selectedValue` property in your element to update the `selected` property via binding.

Initially, I specified the `selectedValue` property in Polymer's `ready` function and it didn't work. I suspect this might be because the `selected` property was set too early, before the repeating templates were rendered.

So instead of setting it inside `ready`, I set it in `attached` -

```
attached: function () {
  this.async(function () {
    this.selectedValue = 1;
  });
}
```

And this time [it](http://plnkr.co/edit/yiZG1j4Ts9T79nUdBgNs?p=preview) works.

Answer (score 3):

To pre-select items in the `paper-dropdown-menu` you can add the properties `selected` and `attr-for-selected` in the element used as `dropdown-content` (e.g. `paper-menu` or `paper-listbox`).

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-listbox attr-for-selected="data-order" selected="1" class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item data-order="0">First</paper-item>
    <paper-item data-order="1">Second</paper-item>
    <paper-item data-order="2">Third</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```